# How to test the existance of an instance of a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object, instance, exists

I have this:

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        Animate();

        function Animate() {
            if (true) { // What do change here for the object to self-check if it still exists?
                console.log('1');
                requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
            }
        }
    }
}

var dog = new Animal();

setTimeout(function () {
    dog = undefined;
    // The Animate() should no longer be called at this point.
}, 3000);
```

How can I modify the *Animate()* function to stop calling itself again if the instance of the class no longer "exist"...?

---

Thank you for all the responses. Like some have stated below, it seems like I would need to implement some kind of "destroy" method to handle and manage the Animate() function call for the instance of the class Animal. Not really what I would want as I'd rather the instance to self-aware and know when it is no longer needed.

Not sure if this will help clarify some questions below, but we could have:

```
var dog1 = new Animal();
var dog2 = new Animal();
var dog3 = new Animal();
```

Each of those instances will run its own `Animate()`.  The moment the instance if set to undefined (for example, could be set to null also), the `Animate()` call should not be called anymore. The goal here is to get the instance of the object to be self-aware it was no longer needed. Creating a destroy method would imply we are making the call externally and thus the instance is not self-aware.

If we used jQuery, we could add a $(this)(0).length within the class to detect if the object still exists.

Comment: I'd rather not use setTimeout as it will force the browser to work very hard to a point where performance will degrade overtime.  It definitely has to be called using requestAnimationFrame().

Comment: The object will continue to exist as long as `Animate` refers to it (which it has to), the `dog` variable is irrelevant for that. You cannot check for the "existence" of an object you're holding. What you need to do is to explicitly set some kind of `.destroyed` flag, or call a `.stopAnimation()` method which cancels the animation frame.

Comment: In addition to what @Bergi already did mention ... for any GUI related class one should anyhow consider providing a `destroy` method to it. And since one most likely has child and parent relationships of GUI elements too, one easily ensures/establishes entire destroy/destructure chains.

Comment: "*I'd rather the instance to self-aware and know when it is no longer needed.*" - this is not possible. Notice that not the "instance" is set to `undefined`, but just one variable that's currently holding it. "*Creating a destroy method would imply we are making the call externally*" - there's not much of a difference between your desired `dog2 = undefined` and `dog2.destroy()`.

Comment: "*If we used jQuery, we could add a `$(this)(0).length` within the class to detect if the object still exists.*" - uh, no, jQuery is not magic and it cannot detect either if a jQuery instance still exists. What you *can* do - both with jQuery and plain DOM methods - is to detect whether an element is still part of the `document` or was removed from the DOM. This might even be a reasonable solution if you are animating DOM elements, but we don't know from your question what the `Animal`'s `Animate` function is actually doing. (Also it still should be `dog2.destroy()` that removes the element).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd just use:

```
  if (dog) {
    requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
  }
```

When `dog` is `undefined`, this is "falsy".

Comment: This doesn't work for `var dog = new Animal(), cat = new Animal();` when only some of the objects get "removed" after the 3s.

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand what you're getting at.  Is this question not just trying to determine if there is a value for the variable `dog`?

Comment: No, I think the goal is for `Animate` to determine whether "the current `Animal` instance" still exists. If there was only a single `dog` variable that the OP cared about, they wouldn't have used a `class`.

Comment: @MightyMouse Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Brad's solution but as an answer to the original question, you can use the `instanceof` keyword to test that something is an instance of another class.

For the code you referenced:

```js
if (dog instanceof Animal) {
    console.log('1');
    requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
}
```